# CSS property overflow:hidden causes inner divs to appear below main div

Tags: css, overflow, hidden

Is there a way to make my `#inner_div` stop appearing behind the `#main_di`v if it exceeds a certain width? I tried removing the `overflow:hidden` from `#main_div` in css but that causes the background of the `#main_div` to load very slowly, so I would like to find another solution if possible. Thanks

**Main div css:**

```
#main_div {
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 3px 0 #BBBBBB, 0 4px 0 #AAAAAA, 0 5px 3px #444444;
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F6F6F6;
   border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
   margin: 20px auto;
   overflow: hidden; 
   padding: 10px;
   width: 970px;
}
```

**Inner div css:**

```
.inner_div{
   font-size:12px;
   font-weight:normal;
   font-style:normal;
   margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: #000000;
   z-index: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   /* white-space: nowrap;*/
   text-align: left;
   padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `overflow:hidden`, you should use the new "micro clearfix".

Go here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

In your markup, you simply just add the class "cf" on #main_div